# Expressing functional dependency given trigonometric relations

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Given (assuming $0 \leq t \leq \pi/2$)

```
x == (1 + a Sin[2 t]) Sin[t],
```

and

```
y == 1 - (1 + a Sin[2 t]) Cos[t]
```

How can I get $y(x)$ without the $t$ variable appearing?

Solving for, and eliminating, $t$ directly proved very awkward and this didn't work:

```
Assuming[0 < t < \[Pi]/2,
 Eliminate[{x == (1 + a Sin[2 t]) Sin[t],
   y == 1 - (1 + a  Sin[2 t]) Cos[t] }, t]]
```

Answer (score 7):

The usual procedure for obtaining a Cartesian equation from parametric equations like yours is to use `GroebnerBasis[]` for eliminating variables:

```
First[GroebnerBasis[Append[TrigExpand[{x == (1 + a Sin[2 t]) Sin[t],
                                       y == 1 - (1 + a Sin[2 t]) Cos[t]}], 
                           Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t]^2 == 1],
                    {x, y, a}, {Cos[t], Sin[t]}]]
   -4 a x + x^2 - 4 a^2 x^2 - 4 a x^3 + 2 x^4 + x^6 - 2 y + 12 a x y - 8 x^2 y +
   8 a^2 x^2 y + 4 a x^3 y - 6 x^4 y + 9 y^2 - 12 a x y^2 + 16 x^2 y^2 -
   4 a^2 x^2 y^2 + 3 x^4 y^2 - 16 y^3 + 4 a x y^3 - 12 x^2 y^3 + 14 y^4 +
   3 x^2 y^4 - 6 y^5 + y^6
```

The result obtained is a degree-$6$ polynomial, so I am not very sanguine about solving for `y` in this case.

Comment: An excellent first step (+1).

Comment: `Solve[gb==0, y, Reals]  ` gives you solutions, but you have to pick the right ones.

Comment: @Akku, since the result contains `Root[]` objects (as expected), I don't particularly care for solving for `y`, as it is not more convenient than the starting implicit equation.